# Unit Testing a RedirectToAction with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit

I have an MVC Controller Class that I am trying to Unit Test.

The particular ActionResult is like this

```
public ActionResult Create(Shipment newShipment)
{
   do some stuff to create a shipmentID
...
   return RedirectToAction("AddUnit",newShipment.ShipmentID);
}
```

I have mocked up the controller context etc and now I want to test that the newShipment.ShipmentID passed to the RedirectToAction call is what I expect.

I have a test (with lots of mocking of things in the setup phase)

```
    [Test]
    public void CreateSuccess()
    {
        //Arrange
        var shipment = new Shipment();
        shipment.Widgets = 2; //Make sure it a valid shipment otherwise
        //Act
        var result = controller.Create(shipment) as RedirectToRouteResult;
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("AddUnits", result.RouteValues["action"]);
        Assert.IsNull(result.RouteValues["controller"]);
        ...
```

And now I want to find an Assert to check that the shipmentID I pass to RedirectToAction is the right one.  How do I retrieve its value?

(I believe this code works for real (ie the actual view gets the correct shipmentID) but I want to write  a unit test ).

Comment: Can you change the Create function to pass arguement by reference as below: public ActionResult Create(ref Shipment newShipment)? If so, you can simply Do Assert.IsEqual(shipment.shipmentID, yourvalue);

Comment: I don't have much control as to how the Create function is called - this is ASP.NET MVC and its this framework which in the real application is calling create.

Comment: I think I was probably mistaken about the ability for RedirectToAction to carry parameters - I think they go in to TempData.  Anyway in the end I reworked the controller to return a View instead.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, RedirectToActions can take parameters; below is a simplified example of how I tested for correct parameters in one. I'm using NUnit & FluentAssertions here.

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult RedirectMethod()
{
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { parameter = "Value" });
}
```

and then the test:

```
[Test]
public void RedirectSetsExpectedParameters()
{
    var result = controller.RedirectMethod();
    var redirectResult = result.As<RedirectToRouteResult>();

    var expectedRedirectValues = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "parameter", "Value" },
            { "action", "Index" },
            { "controller", "Home" }
        };

    redirectResult
       .RouteValues
       .ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedRedirectValues, 
       "The redirect should look as I expect, including the parameters");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort to try and answer my nearly 3 year old question.  Its so long ago and with technology I haven't used since I have no clue as to your answers relevance or correctness.

Comment: No worries! I just added it for posterity, since I was trying to solve the same problem recently.

Answer (score 2):

Here i given one sample for Redirect to action

```
public ActionResult Signupsuccess(string account_code, string plan)
{
   ..........
  do some stuff

  return RedirectToAction("SubscriptionPlan", "Settings");

}
```

I have mocked up controllercontext and passed some parameter to RedirectToAction call from controller to test method.Finally it tested both the expected and actual

[TestMethod()]

```
 public void SignupsuccessTest()
       {
            HomeController target = new HomeController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string account_code = "B898YB7"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string plan = "Application-BASIC"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value

            var ControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            var context = target.HttpContext;

            ControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Session["MerchantID"]).Returns("15");
            ControllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Session["FriendlyIdentifier"]).Returns("3d649876-19f5-48d2-af03-ca89083ae712");

            target.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;       

            var action = (RedirectToRouteResult)target.Signupsuccess(account_code, plan);

            action.RouteValues["action"].Equals("SubscriptionPlan");
            action.RouteValues["controller"].Equals("Settings");

            Assert.AreEqual("SubscriptionPlan", action.RouteValues["action"]);
            Assert.AreEqual("Settings", action.RouteValues["controller"]);          
        }
```

I Hope really it will helpful for you.Thank You