# Xunit Testing on Visual Studio Assertion for The RedirectToAction Method

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, xunit

How to write assert for the following piece of code on ASP.NET Core 6.0

If (result != null)

return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", routeValues);

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374557/unit-testing-a-redirecttoaction-with-parameter) original question.
You can write a test to check if current action name and controller name is being returned when your piece of code is called.

For example -

This is my controller -

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string secretName)
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("TestAction", "WeatherForecast");
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest("Error: Unable to read secret");
        }
    }
```

and this is my unit test -

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Mock<WebApplication1.Abstract.IKeyValutManager> secretManager = new Mock<IKeyValutManager>();
        Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<WeatherForecastController>> logger = new Mock<ILogger<WeatherForecastController>>(MockBehavior.Loose);
        WeatherForecastController controller = new WeatherForecastController(logger.Object, secretManager.Object);

        var result = controller.Get("test");

        Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result.Result);
        var redirectionResult = (RedirectToActionResult)result.Result;
        Assert.True((redirectionResult.ActionName.CompareTo("TestAction")) ==0);
        Assert.True((redirectionResult.ControllerName.CompareTo("WeatherForecast")) == 0);
        //redirectionResult.RouteValues["controller"].Equals("WeatherForecast");
    }
```